# How can I compare robust linear mixed models and get the p-values, F statistic, AIC and BIC?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mixed-model, aic, robust

I need to fit a linear mixed model but my dependent variable is has some outliers that I can't discard. Then I used the `rlmer()` function (`robustlmm` package).

All this works fine. Nevertheless, I'm trying to compare several models and I need to get the p-values. AICc, BIC and the F-values. Is there any function that does this?

Answer (score 3):

In robust linear mixed models, there is no AIC and BIC given that no likelihood exists for this kind of model. Regarding p-values, they seem bad if you try to calculate them using bootstrapping methods. It's better to use confidence intervals instead. These can be calculated using wald-type tests.

Comment: Hi @gung, this is not a proper answer to the question since the question is about a function but the answer counts the + and - and in the end it suggests sung CI. -1

Comment: @TPArrow, this isn't my answer, I only edited it. It's true that the question asked for a function, but IMHO, sometimes the answer that will most benefit an OP is to unpack the assumptions made in the question & point out that they aren't really appropriate.

Comment: @gung oh right! However, the credit should be made for a proper answer, IMHO.

Comment: @Wagliss, Could you provide any reference about confidence intervals are better than p-values when performing robust linear mixed models? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes late to the OP but I found this post trying to get the answer to the OP's question and then later found part of the answer. @Wagliss is correct that you cannot obtain an AIC or BIC for robust models because there is no likelihood estimation in these situations. The makers of the `robustlmm` package provide means to obtain p-values using the `TestFixef` function. For more info check out the github [Robustlmm Github](https://nam11.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FmasonFG%2FCIrobustLMM&data=04%7C01%7Cparks.t.marion%40wmich.edu%7C537db4b67a6b420cc1eb08da1fd20551%7C257622517aa94c72905f39bf026a8a84%7C0%7C0%7C637857284593055582%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000&sdata=lbD6D%2BzRNq9enoscwgwJVgDzwbbeiAMUG4EhkksV40I%3D&reserved=0).